# Save Pandas data frame from list of dicts as hdf5 table

Tags: database, pandas, dataframe, pytables, zodb

I have a large pandas data frame that I create from a list of dictionaries where the column names are the dict keys. The columns contain different types of data, but the datatype is consistent in any given column.

Example: one of my columns contains 28x28 numpy arrays and another contains strings...etc. I would like to save this out as an HDF5 file, having table format so I can query the data when reading it in later (these files are ~1-2 GB).

This is how I'm trying to save the hdf5 file:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dicts)

df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True) (**have also tried pd.to_numeric)**

df.to_hdf(path_to_save, 'df', format='table')
```

And I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot serialize the column [image_dims] because
>   its data contents are [mixed] object dtype

The image_dims column in this case has a numpy array for each entry, and this happens on any column that has an object datatype in pandas, I am not sure how to change/set it. I can save it as fixed format but I'd really like to use tables to save on loading time, etc, with queries. I've seen some other questions similar to this, but not with regard to creating the data frame from a list of dictionaries, which may be causing the problem?

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

you changed your DF in memory - `df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)` - will return a copy of converted DF, but it WON'T change the original DF. Do it this way instead:

```
df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').to_hdf(path_to_save, 'df', format='table')
```

or

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric)
df['image_dims'] = df['image_dims'].astype(str) # in case it can't be converted to numeric
df.to_hdf(path_to_save, 'df', format='table')
```

PS you may want to use `errors='coerce'` or  `errors='ignore'` parameter when calling `pd.to_numeric(...)` function, depending on what you want

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the first solution would work I think except that I get this error: Type Error arg must be a list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series. It works on individual series, but I need it on the whole data frame. Also did you mean that calling convert objects on a separate line caused the change in memory? As in it didn't operate in place to convert the columns but copied the data frame?

Comment: @notarya, `DataFrame.convert_objects()` - returns converted DF, but it doesn't change the original DF, so you'll need: `df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)`

Comment: thanks. I think the issue now is that some of my columns have string entries and some are numeric, so now I'm running into this issue:     

ValueError: ('Unable to parse string', u'occurred at index axis_view')

I may have to manually convert columns or loop through them and convert to a numeric type that way.

Comment: @notarya, you can try to do it this way: `df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')`, but it doesn't make much sense to convert strings (that don't represent numbers) to numeric dtype. You can also prepare a list of columns that must be converted and use it as a filter

Comment: yeah I tried that but I get the same mixed object dtype error. I might try a sqlite approach if I can't figure out a better way than manually changing columns.

Comment: @notarya, just convert all columns pandas complaining about to `str` or 'object' dtype, before calling `to_hdf()`

Comment: not to be annoyingly repeating the same thing - but pandas/pytables seems to disagree with having numpy datatypes in dataframes (in terms of serializing the columns). Anyway, I'm still getting the same error even manually converting the columns with the problematic datatype. I'll keep trying to get creative - feel free to make suggestions if you have the, and thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

After trying many things I finally found what seems to be a good solution for saving mixed datatype objects in a way that they can be loaded quickly and queried. I thought I'd post it in case someone else is having trouble with this:

Tried and failed: Pandas data frame save as hdf5 or json files. Hdf5 works but only in fixed format (no querying capability) when data types are mixed. Json works with mixed but is no faster to load for files of this size. Tried converting all numpy arrays, lists, etc to byte strings for saving: this was more trouble than it was worth with the number of columns and different data types I'm dealing with.

Solution: Use ZODB (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ZODB). Object database that was very easy to implement, and is easy to integrate with pandas if data frames are your thing.

```
from ZODB.FileStorage import FileStorage
from ZODB.DB import DB
import transaction
storage = FileStorage('path_to_store.fs')
db = DB(storage)
connection = db.open()
root = connection.root()
# insert each column of the dataframe into the db
for col in df.columns:
    root[col] = df[col]
# commit changes to the db
transaction.commit()
# works like a dictionary with key:value pairs that correspond to column names
print root.keys()

# close db and connection
db.close()
connection.close()
```

You can then read a database with the same syntax, and access data through the root variable.